# How to let the admin get noticed when 500 errors occurred in nginx?

Tags: monitoring, nginx, gentoo

How to let the admin get noticed when 500 errors occurred in nginx?

Comment: Just for some attempted clarification. Do you want to setup an alert to the admin (you, presumably) if the number of errors on your webserver reaches a certain threshold, in this case 500?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I use a commercial service at http://www.wormly.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could do something with a bash script, like

```
#!/bin/bash

b=`grep 'error' -c /var/log/nginx.log`

if [[ $b -gt 500 ]] ; then
echo "more than 500 errors";
# or send an email

else
#echo "OK" > /dev/null 2>&1

fi
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if [[ $b > 500 ]]`?

Comment: `[[` does not support comparison using `>`; you need either `-gt`/`-lt` or `(( ))`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B.5B_.24foo_.3E_7_.5D.5D

Comment: Hi grawity, thanks for the fix, I updated the script :)

Answer (score 4):

Most monitoring systems, whether they're software you install like Nagios or Zabbix or monitoring services such as Panopta or Pingdom, can be configured to detect 500 responses as errors and alert you to investigate.  The benefit of using a full monitoring system is that you can get SMS or voice alerts in addition to just emails.  You can also get notified if the server itself goes down or loses all connectivity, which a local cron script wouldn't be able to handle.

Comment: Yes but Pingdom cannot tell you when there's a 500 error occurring during signups from a particular country while a local script can.

Answer (score 0):

No matter you use scripts or monitoring systems. 
You can used "curl" to check the http status code.